# 500 Internal Server Error When Uploading Images Using PHP

Tags: php, upload

I'm offering users the ability to upload files using an online form, but I keep on getting 500 internal server errors whenever the file upload is processed. This is what I know:

- The problem isn't related to php.ini. I've checked the max file upload size, and it's set at 2 megabytes. I get the same 500 internal server error uploading 3kb large files, as well as 100kb large files.
- The problem isn't related to file permissions. The php file I'm using to upload, `upload.php`, has permissions set to 664, and the upload folder, called `upload_pic`, has folder permissions of 755.
- This is not an issue with the code. The exact same code was working on my previous server. I recently bought a new server and am migrating the sites over, and this is where I'm getting my problem.

I've looked online for the past two days, but I just can't find what's causing the problem. I've seen many issues similar to mine, but most of these were resolved by changing file/directory permissions, or making edits to php.ini.

Does anyone have any other proposed solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Does you form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?

Comment: Have you looked through [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) & also, have you double-checked the value of **MAX_FILE_SIZE** in your form, as mentioned [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)?

Comment: Do you have suExec configured on your server or is your `upload_pic` owned by `www-data`? Otherwise folder permissions of 755 isn't ok.

Comment: It sounds like you have a module missing. Have you looked at your webserver logs? There should be a PHP error in there saying what it is looking.

Comment: @quickshiftin There is no `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in the code.

Comment: check tmp dir if it exists

Comment: @CharlesTian I know, that's something in the HTML, if you looked at the page...

Comment: @quickshiftin Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. What exactly is in the HTML?

Comment: Just read the web page on the link, it allows the browser to tell the client if they're uploading a file bigger than the limit on the server without having to upload the whole thing first to find out.

Comment: @quickshiftin How will that solve the 500 internal server error though?

Comment: Not sure if it will help the 500, but it couldn't hurt.